# Comentários de um usuário com nome igual ficam "Acesos" como se fosse eu

Tags: bug, status-intencional

Recentemente estava em uma fila de análise e vi um comentário de um usuário que possui o mesmo nome que eu, que seria [este aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/5149/paulo-roberto), percebi que ele estava "Aceso" como se fosse eu que tivesse comentado.

Veja a imagem abaixo:

[image: bug do usuario]

**Acredito que isto seja um bug, estou certo?**

Comment: Por curiosidade, pode postar o link para os dois usuários?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Isso aconteceu porque o Paulo Roberto (que não é você) é o autor daquela pergunta.

Qualquer um que for [na pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5710/compartilhar-textos-no-facebook-phonegap#comment9230_5710) vai ver o nome dele realçado.

Comment: nossa, é verdade, me esqueci disso!